# Metro horizontal scrolling container using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-metro, winjs

Is there a standard way to achieve the horizontal scrolling effect in metro applications using WinJS / javascript ?

Say I have mulitple divs **added dynamically** with variable width/height and I want the screen to scroll horizontally when the content is wider when overflowing, how would I go about to achieve that?

I would prefer not to use overflow-x:scroll with a fixed width on a scroll wrapper

```
<section class="header">
    Header which is always shown in top left corner
</section>
<section class="magic-winjs-scroll-container-class">
   <div style="width:300px;height:200px">Some random div which should stack horizontally</div>
   <div style="width:300px;height:200px">Some random div which should stack horizontally</div>
   <div style="width:300px;height:200px">Some random div which should stack horizontally</div>
   <div style="width:300px;height:200px">Some random div which should stack horizontally</div>
   <div style="width:300px;height:200px">Some random div which should stack horizontally</div>
   <div style="width:300px;height:200px">Some random div which should stack horizontally</div>
</section>
```

**Solution:**

***CSS***

```
.magic-winjs-scroll-container-class {
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a "Flexbox". This will give you everything that you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

Additonally, there is a hands on lab with interactive CSS generation for the different options:
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_flex.htm

Specifically, you'll want it to lay out in rows. You will still need overflow: auto, to make it allow you to show scrollbars automatically.

After that, it's all down to tweaking the flexbox to make it layout how you would like it.

Note, that if this is for lots of data, you might want to consider using the ListView, which achieves this in a completely different way, but allows for data & UI virtualization.

THe

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out and get back to you. Do you have any code examples (css) from use of flexbox?

Comment: Yeha, the MSDN link has worked examples for the different scenario. I also added a link to the hands on interactive page that helps you visualize the different options, and generate the CSS you need.

Comment: Note that the hands on example uses -ms-box however in WinJS it is -ms-flexbox

Comment: For the record, MSFT help and direction around this *incredibly basic* kind of stuff is *horrendous*. It's such a waste of time trying to figure this stuff out.